# Laravel routing: The requested was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I just set up an Ubuntu environment on Amazon to run my Laravel application. However, I cannot access my routes, which work fine on my local machine (MAMP).

When trying to access `ip/recipe-site/public/recipes` I am met with the following error:

```
The requested URL /recipe-site/public/recipes was not found on this server.
```

However, I can reach `ip/recipe-site/public/` just fine, which leads me to suspect something is wrong with my Apache configuration.

What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The routes don't work because you've probably put the app straight into `/var/www/html` and are serving traffic directly from there instead of `/var/www/html/recipe-site/public`

Laravel deconstructs the URL you used to access the website and then determines what route it'll serve up depending on that.

If your url looks like `127.0.0.1/recipe-site/public/recipes`, laravel will go looking for the route `recipe-site/public/recipes` and I'm guessing your route is just `recipes`.

To fix this, you'll need to change the `DocumentRoot` setting in the apache config to reflect where the projects public folder is.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/recipe-site/public
```

You'll then just be accessing the project by the IP address, making your url resemble `127.0.0.1/recipes`, at which point, laravel will go looking for the route `recipes`.

The app works when you head to `ip/recipe-site/public` because apache will, by default, serve up the index.php file sitting in `public` and you'll be getting the default route.

You may also want to double check that `mod_rewrite` is enabled.